# Error message after switching from BibTeX to BibLaTeX

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

I switched from BiBTeX to BiBLaTeX.
I followed the instructions from lockstep in this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5091/what-to-do-to-switch-to-biblatex).
I use JabRef for generating a .bib file.

Here is a MWE of my `main.tex` file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt, twoside, openright]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref} %for links to figures, chapters, references,...
\usepackage[refpage]{nomencl} %for making list of abbreviations
\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage{subcaption} %for subfigures
\usepackage{siunitx}  %for displaying nice ranges in SI units
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[english]{babel}% Recommended
\usepackage{csquotes}% Recommended
\usepackage[bibstyle = numeric, sorting = none]{biblatex}
    \addbibresource{ReferencesMA.bib}

\author{Me}
\title{sometitle}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}



\frontmatter
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\include{./Chapters/Chapter01}
\include{./Chapters/Chapter02}

\backmatter

%\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
%\bibliography{ReferencesMA}
\printbibliography
% bibliography, glossary and index would go here.

\end{document}
```

For build and view I used the following workflow: PdfLatex, Biber, PdfLatex, PdfLatex, Internal PdfViewer.

If I use BiBTeX instead of biblatex and substitute Biber by Bibtex, it works. However, I'd like to use BiBLaTeX.

The first error of a large list of error is `File ended while scanning use of \field. \begin{document}`.

I tried deleting all files which are generated during the build and retried the process. That didn't help.
If it is of any help, here is the content of the `main.log` : [many rows!](http://pastebin.com/BZDMdpcN)

Here is my .bib-file: [.bib-file](http://pastebin.com/Kk8GDia7)

What should I do? If I forgot to mention something I'll try to add the info as fast as possible.

Comment: Did you delete all auxiliary files before switching to `biblatex` and `biber`?

Comment: Yes, I deleted the main.aux and the .aux files of the included chapters before I tried to use biblatex and biber.

Comment: Could you post  your .bib file? Maybe it has syntax error.

Comment: I edited my post and included a pastebin-link to my bib file.
You can find it here: http://pastebin.com/Kk8GDia7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused by the entry `Wang2007`

```
@Article{Wang2007,
 author   = {F. Wang and J. Mei and Xinhua Wu},
 title    = {Compositionally graded Ti6Al4V + TiC made by direct laser fabrication using powder and wire},
 journal  = {Materials \& Design},
 year     = {2007},
 volume   = {28},
 number   = {7},
 pages    = {2040 - 2046},
  abstract = {Ti6Al4V reinforced with TiC has been fabricated as compositionally graded material by direct laser fabrication using TiC powder and Ti6Al4V wire which were fed simultaneously into the laser focal point. The microstructure along the length of the sample has been characterised using X-ray diffraction and scanning electron microscopy. The results show that the composition along the length changes as expected from the imposed changes in feed rate when allowance is made for the different capture efficiency for the powder and the wire. Some unmelted TiC has been observed in regions where the TiC fraction was high, but along most of the length of the samples TiC was completely melted and formed primary TiC, eutectic TiC and secondary TiC. Some preliminary tribological properties of the compositionally graded material were obtained using a sliding wear test which showed that the tribological properties of Ti6Al4V are improved by the reinforced TiC particles with the optimum frictional behaviour being found with approximately 24 vol% of TiC. },
  doi      = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.matdes.2006.06.010},
 issn     = {0261-3069},
 keywords = {Direct laser fabrication, Functionally graded materials, TiC-reinforced titanium alloys },
 url      = {http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0261306906001920},
}
```

Specifically, in the `abstract` field you have an unescaped `%`: `24 vol%`.
The `%` starts a comment in the `.bbl` file causing LaTeX to ignore everything after the `24 vol`, so the group in the `.bbl` file is not properly closed leading to the error message

```
! File ended while scanning use of \field.
```

You can escape the `%` to get rid of the problem.

```
Some preliminary tribological properties of the compositionally graded material were obtained using a sliding wear test which showed that the tribological properties of Ti6Al4V are improved by the reinforced TiC particles with the optimum frictional behaviour being found with approximately 24 vol\% of TiC.
```

Or you tell Biber to ignore the `abstract` field:

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldset=abstract, null]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this solved my problem! But how come that this issue didn't happen with bibtex?

Comment: @DavidP Most `.bst` styles don't know the `abstract` field and ignore it so that it is not written to the `.bbl` file. But Biber knows the field and writes it to the `.bbl`.